# How to use winston logger in mean stack application

Tags: typescript, mean-stack, winston

I'm banging my head to use 'winston' logger in my mean stack application. My aim is: i want to use two loggers (for now). one for, http request logging which will be written to request.log file and another will be application logging, which will be written to app.log file. I fillowed each and every tutorial but i'm not able to make it work.

I've installed dependencies,'winston' and 'morgan', in my application and configured below `winston.js` file and loaded in app.js.

```
var appRoot = require('app-root-path');
var winston = require('winston');

// define the custom settings for each transport (file, console)
var options = {
    appLog: {
        level: 'debug',
        filename: `${appRoot}/logs/app.log`,
        handleExceptions: true,
        json: true,
        maxsize: 5242880, // 5MB
        maxFiles: 5,
        colorize: false,
    },
    requestLog: {
        level: 'info',
        filename: `${appRoot}/logs/request.log`,
        handleExceptions: true,
        json: false,
        maxsize: 5242880, // 5MB
        maxFiles: 5,
        colorize: false,
    },
    console: {
        level: 'info',
        handleExceptions: true,
        json: false,
        colorize: true,
    }
};

// instantiate a new Winston Logger with the settings defined above
var appLogger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.File(options.appLog),
        new winston.transports.Console(options.console)
    ],
    exitOnError: false, // do not exit on handled exceptions
});

var reqLogger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.File(options.requestLog),
    ],
    exitOnError: false, // do not exit on handled exceptions
});

// create a stream object with a 'write' function that will be used by `morgan`
reqLogger.stream = {
    write: function (message, encoding) {
        // use the 'info' log level so the output will be picked up by both transports (file and console)
        reqLogger.info(message);
    }
};

module.exports = appLogger;
module.exports = reqLogger;
```

This i loaded in `app.js` file as shown below:

```
var morgan = require('morgan');
var winston = require('./config/winston');
app.use(morgan('combined', { stream: winston.stream }));
```

So, i can redirect request logs to request.log and application log. I have two questions now:

How to use `appLogger' instance in my application *.component.ts files??
Everywhere over internet i see below code:

```
var logger = require('winston'); 
logger.debug("blah blah blah");
```

But when i use same in my *.component.ts files i'm getting below error:

```
TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'
```

Please help me out. Can't we use 'winston' logger with typescript files?? Whats the best way to do server side logging (ts files & js files) in mean stack application??

Comment: Have you tried `import morgan = require('morgan');` ?

Comment: @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir  `error TS1202: Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript modules. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"', 'import d from "mod"', or another module format instead.`

Comment: @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir i think `morgan` is for http request logging. I want `winston` to work in my application code ie., *.component.ts files